# is it possible to stop firefox from keeping user input data on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, textinput

I have noticed that firefox retains input data in elements such as text input fields and scroll position, i think this makes the user input on my web page very slow. is there a way to disable this feature?

the profiler says messageQueue.push is the culprit.

my reasoning is that chrome does not retain data on refresh and the user input runs very quickly.

i am using php, HTML5 and javascript.

any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:

`echo"<td><input type='text' id='".$a."-".$b."-inc"."' autocomplete='off'></td>";`

this is the way i create the the inputs now and still the user input is very slow and freezes any ideas why this would happen on firefox and not chrome?

Comment: See this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp ; in future you may want to insert more initial (detailed) data, sample form etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added the autocomplete='off', but no change. should i create a new question now that i am baffled at the cause of the slow input speed?